# ArrayFormula with ADD function with multiple IF in google sheet

Tags: array-formulas

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((Q2:Q)<250001,0,IF(AND((Q2:Q)>250000,(Q2:Q)
<500001),ROUND(((Q2:Q)-250000)*0.05,0),IF(AND((Q2:Q)>500000,(Q2:Q)
<1000001),ROUND(((Q2:Q)-500000)*0.2,0)+12500,ROUND(((Q2:Q)-
1000000)*0.3,0)+112500))))
```

The resulting value is error. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`()` is not required for range, try this

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Q2:Q<250001,0,IF(AND(Q2:Q>250000,Q2:Q<500001),ROUND((Q2:Q-
250000)*0.05,0),IF(AND(Q2:Q>500000,Q2:Q
<1000001),ROUND((Q2:Q-500000)*0.2,0)+12500,ROUND((Q2:Q-1000000)*0.3,0)+112500))))
```